# How to invoke angularjs function from external js file - d3 chart

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I have below code in Angularjs javascript file which is powering d3js radar chart

**chart.js**

```
ui.d3.TsPlot = function(element) {
  this._element = element;
  this._plotRadius = 41;
  this._padding = 7;
  this._interpolation = 'linear-closed';
  this._editable = false;
  this._tooltips = true;
  this._animated = true;
  this._freeDraw = false;
  this._exps = [];
.........
};

ui.tsplot = function() {
       function link(scope, element, attrs) {
       var tsPlot = new ui.d3.TsPlot(element[0])
      .setPlotRadius(parseInt(attrs.plotRadius, 10))
       .setInnerRadius(parseInt(attrs.innerRadius, 10))
     // Some other assignments for TsPlot
  }
}

angular
 .module('ui.tsplot', [])
 .directive('tsPlot', ui.tsplot);
```

I would like to call tsplot() in my javascript function in the template.

**home.html**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function retry()
    {
            alert('Before assignment');
            var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("tsPlot")).scope();
            scope.ui.tsplot();
            alert('After assignment');
    }
```

However second alert never runs when I invoke retry() function, when I checked the console, browser throws an error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined"

Below code I use in my template

```
 <script>
        var app = angular.module('tsPlotExampleApp', ['ui.tsplot']);
        app.controller('tsPlotCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dyndata={};
   });
</script>
```

What am I missing in retry(), what should I do to invoke ui.tsplot() in retry?

Objective of this is to load the d3 function as I have dynamically created the charts.

Comment: It isn't very clear what the following means: `I have below code for my d3 chart in Angularjs javascript file`. In what context is `ui.tsplot` defined? Can you show "the surroundings"?

Comment: Hi @tasseKATT , I have added some details in the question. Could you please check it now?

Comment: Is that really the code for `ui.tsplot`? It doesn't look correct. It needs to return the link function.

Comment: yea.. it was huge, so I haven't included.. its here  --     return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      dsn: '=',
      compare: '=',
      play: '=',
      stack: '='
    },
    link: link
  };
};

Comment: The `ui.tsplot` function is the entire factory funciton that you register as your `tsPlot` directive, is that really the function you want to call? That function only returns the directive definition object. And it isn't availble as a method on the scope.

Comment: Oh. ok, I was using this for a chart actually.. Am trying to dynamically create the chart div's.. Am able to create them, but I see there is no svg that is getting generated for these dynamically created chart divs.. for that reason, I would like to reinvoke entire d3.tsplot.. I see there are several functions in it, not sure which one to invoke..

Comment: Try to wrap the code in your link function in a call to `$timeout` like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018191/angularjs-jquery-datatable-empty/23027479#23027479